# Make react bootstrap tabs only show in only one row

Tags: reactjs, tabs, react-bootstrap

I am using react bootstrap tabs, i want to show them in only one row like sublime or atom, but the problem is they will auto break line when they reach the the width of container.
Anyone knows how i can do that.
Thanks so much!
Below is my code, just using simple tabs of react bootstrap

```
return (
  <div>
    <Tabs>
      {this.props.tabState.map(function(v, i, obj) {
        return (
          <Tab key={i} eventKey={i} title={titleWithBtn(v, i)} >
            {childrenWithProps({file:v, tabIndex:i})}
          </Tab>
        )
      })}
    </Tabs>
  </div>
);
```

**Solution** 
I can do this perfectly by using this [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-draggable-tab)

Answer (score 2):

Checked the `Tabs` structure, it used `ul` and `li` to create the tabs, and class that get applied is `.nav-tabs`, do the changes in that class. Put this style in `head` of `html` file it will work:

```
<style type="text/css">
   .nav-tabs {
        display: inline-flex !important;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: I'm using react-bootstrap and this doesn't work for me. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Set width of each tab, down font-size, for examble two tabs set each tap 50% width and keep reduce.